# Trying to understaning symfony RoleHierarchy

Tags: symfony, symfony-security

I am reading [RoleHierarchy](http://api.symfony.com/3.2/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Role/RoleHierarchy.html) class in Symfony Security module and trying to make sense of following code:

```
  public function getReachableRoles(array $roles)
    {
        $reachableRoles = $roles;
        foreach ($roles as $role) {
            if (!isset($this->map[$role->getRole()])) {
                continue;
            }

            foreach ($this->map[$role->getRole()] as $r) {
                $reachableRoles[] = new Role($r);
            }
        }

        return $reachableRoles;
    }
```

The documentation says something like this:

> Returns an array of all reachable roles by the given ones.
>
> Reachable roles are the roles directly assigned but also all roles
>   that are transitively reachable from them in the role hierarchy.

Lets say I have

```
 $role = new RoleHierarchy(array(
        'ROLE_ADMIN' => array('ROLE_USER'),
        'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN' => array('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_FOO'),
    ));
```

According to the function description (as I understand) following test might have failed, but it will not because the function itself seems to return same values as passed as argument if it's not finding the role in map array.

```
$this->assertEquals([new Role('ROLE_BAR')],$role->getReachableRoles([new Role('ROLE_BAR')]));
```

So my question is why its not even validating the `ROLE_BAR` exists or defined in role hierarchy map, or probably I am not getting the function description or missing some other aspect of how roles work. My current understanding is ( might be wrong) that, for a role to be valid role it should be defined in role hierarchy.

Comment: I think it's not responsibility of `getReachableRoles` to check whether a role exists or not into hierarchy, just to return the reachable roles through passed roles. This should be responsibility of `AccessDecisionManager` and voters like `RoleHierarchyVoter` against the user roles.

Comment: @yceruto So what you are saying is that , a role is valid role even its not defined in role hierarchy, probably that is what they meant by `roles directly assigned`

Comment: `Reachable roles are the roles directly assigned` == to `'ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_FOO'` for `'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN'`. `but also all roles that are transitively reachable from them in the role hierarchy` == to `'ROLE_USER'`.

Comment: It's what this method is about.

Comment: :) yes I understand what you said above, the question is  about `ROLE_BAR`, which is not defined in role hierarchy.

Comment: Yes, I understand you too :), but this method shouldn't check whether unknown roles exists into role hierarchy. Only the reachable if possible.

Comment: When you say "a role is valid" <-- I say: it's not the responsibility of this method. It's not here when Symfony check whether a role is valid or not.

Comment: So to make it clear the test should include another test for role not defined in role hierarchy, just as I did above in  https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Tests/Role/RoleHierarchyTest.php

Comment: The test already there https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Tests/Role/RoleHierarchyTest.php#L26 :) it's the first one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133464/discussion-between-yceruto-and-sakhunzai).

Comment: @yceruto its not define there ,  first test is testing ROLE_USER which define in role hierarchy, which is transitively reachable.